# Trouble adding data-parsley-pattern programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley, and it's great!  I want to add different validators programmatically, depending on locale, using javascript/JQuery.  When I hard-code like so:

```
<input type="text" id="billingPostalCode" 
name="userInput_billingPostalCode" 
value='<c:out value="${param.billingPostalCode}"></c:out>' 
class="form-control" required="" 
data-parsley-pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$" 
data-parsley-error-message="Valid Zip/Postal Code Required"></input>
```

it works great.  However, when I try to add it programmatically, it doesn't.  I have this in a .jsp file:

```
<input type="text" id="billingPostalCode" 
value='<c:out value="${param.billingPostalCode}"></c:out>' 
class="form-control" required="" 
data-parsley-error-message="Valid Zip/Postal Code Required">
</input>
```

And this in .js:

```
$('#billingPostalCode').attr('data-parsley-pattern', "^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$");
```

The attribute gets added (I can inspect the element and see it), but it doesn't validate correctly (it sees valid input as invalid).  I have tried placing the JQuery code both before and after attaching parsley to the form:

```
[here...]
$('#paymentInfoForm').parsley( ... );
[and here...]
```

I have also experimented with the regex, anchored and unanchored, simplified versions, etc.  But like I said, the regex works perfectly when it's hard-coded.

Could there be some interference with JSP?  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should work. Post a working example...

Comment: I tried using a different regexes in my jquery code ( specifically I tried .{5} and \d{5} ).  The first one works, the second one doesn't, so it seems like it's the "\d" that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using [0-9] instead of /d in my regular expression.  It does seem to be a bug, though.  This works as expected:

```
$('#billingPostalCode').attr('data-parsley-pattern', "[0-9]{5}(?:[-\s][0-9]{4})?");
```

but the following code not won't validate anything, and will even break hard-coded validation:

```
$('#billingPostalCode').attr('data-parsley-pattern', "\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?");
```

The problem must be specific to javascript, since it works when hard-coded into the jsp file.